# How to automate SSL certificate to page builder site?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I created Page Builder Application for my clients but I am facing difficulties in SSL creation because of users counts is too large (more than 1000). I know its not right procedure SSL certificate creating manually and restarting for each user which is bad idea. I want to apply SSL certificate automatically who all are pointing my DNS A record.

I am using GCP Cloud with nginx server.

Thank you.

Comment: Set up a system that requests certificates from e.g. Let's Encrypt. More detailed answer is not really possible as we don't know your configuration.

Comment: @vidarlo, i  exactly don't know how to achieve my case ,because of  lots of domain.i need just way of achieve with what kind of technoledgy need for that

Comment: The amount of domains is *why* you should automate it. For how to do this: that's too wide topic for a Q&A forum like this.

Answer (score 2):

You've received recommendations for LetsEncrypt and Certbot, but it doesn't look like you've followed up either of them. Certbot is a script that will automatically create LetsEncrypt certificates and install them directly into the nginx server instances, basically doing all the heavy lifting of the automation you need to do. LetsEncrypt is, of course, a certificate authority, so you're not dealing with self-signed certificates. I strongly recommend looking into Certbot for your application.

Comment: Exactly. CertBot will *certainly* do all the "heavy lifting" with the LetsEncrypt CA... so much so, that you should essentially ***never*** have to look at it, again, or "fix it."

Answer (score 1):

See: `certbot`

You can even load it as a Python module under `pyenv` and/or `virtualenv` for kicks.

Comment: ,do you have any related docs for my case with certbot?

Comment: Not specifically "for your case," but `certbot` is pretty simple, overall... it's literally a Python module, which you can find on pypy and install with `pip`, under many different versions on Python.

It gets "as difficult as" specifying a configuration, with a specific domain name, and having the "right" pieces to allow the certbot servers actually verify challenge/reponse data, on the fly.

Comment: i can't see any certbot with python related docs.kindly share any article if you know.

Comment: `certbot` is a Python module... create your Python environment (preferably under a virtual environment of some sort) and then `pip install certbot` - once that is done, you can start with `certbot --help` (which is common to Python modules, overall)

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar issue before, I was using GCP managed SSL certs.

There is an open request, to add more domains to the SSL cert without recreating the Cert itself
so you could add more domains to a single cert.

If you think this could benefit you, please +1 the [request tracker.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148809372)

Comment: i think you mean SAN certificate but it comes with limitation,i want to install each user each certificate is better idea ,i debugged many pagebuilder sites like wix s and some other page builder they install each user  each certificate.

Comment: No, this is kinda bogus. Adding domains requires you to rewrite the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) within the Cert itself. Changing the contents of the cert in ***ANY*** form causes you to invalidate the cert, period... so it MUST be invalidated and reissued. That's just how the crypto works.

Comment: To make this CLEAR to you, @alrashid-villanueva ... you "solution" basically says you want to add domains to a SSL certificate without telling *the actual server* that you've added domains to it. All of that info is ***encrypted*** inside the certificate. So, there's literally NO way to do this in any secure fashion, right now.